# Nested count in one Query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, nested

I need to count a the amount of unread messages per type of a messages table.

**Table**: Messages

**Fields**:

```
Id Message Type Unread
1   xxxxx   0    0
2   xxxxx   1    0
3   xxxxx   1    0
4   xxxxx   1    1
5   xxxxx   2    0
6   xxxxx   3    0
7   xxxxx   3    1
```

So, **I need a result like this**:

```
For type 0 there is 1 unread message, and a total of 1 message.
For type 1 there are 2 unread messages, and a total of 3 messages.
For type 2 there is 1 unread message, and a total of 1 message.
For type 3 there is 1 unread message, and a total of 2 messages.
```

So far, **I was able to count how many messages I've per type**:

```
SELECT 
    `message_type`, 
    COUNT(`message_type`) AS message_type_count
FROM 
    Messages
GROUP BY `message_type`
```

But, **I also need the amount of unread messages per type**. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: your query has a tipo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT message_type,
       COUNT(message_type) AS message_type_count,
       SUM(Unread = 1) AS unread_count
FROM Messages 
GROUP BY message_type
```